# How to sum up sub-variable to get composite variable

Tags: r, spss, ordinal-data, categorical-data

Many Respondents filled questionniare and each question is represented with a variable like following. Each question has two possible answers : `Agree` and `Disagree` which I have coded to `1` and `0` respectively. I need to summarize the result to two variables like `tax_revenue` and `non_tax_revenue` and use it in cross tabulation.

```
Vraiables:
tax_revenue_a
tax_revenue_b
tax_revenue_c
non_tax_revenue_a
non_tax_revenue_b
non_tax_revenue_c
```

I want to get two variables from these variables `tax_revenue` and `non_tax_revenue` computed from the respective variables to use in cross tabulation with another variables.

Can I simply add up the variables and use it like following

```
tax_revenue = tax_revenue_a + tax_revenue_b + tax_revenue_c
non_tax_revenue = non_tax_revenue_a + non_tax_revenue_b + non_tax_revenue_c
```

It can give us result in the range [0,3]. It could not be used in cross tabulation because each value could not be interpreted. Someone said that by defining variable into two levels - `Agree` and `Disagree`, I have used nominal scale and it cannot be added. So I am extremely confused.

How can I compute the variables in better way? Can it be re-coded in two range of values for Agree and Disagree? How do do it? Can the total be broken in mean? or do I have to use different kind of summarization? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your meaning, the answer can be divided thusly:

**regarding adding the variables** - dichotomous variable's *can* be added, it just changes the meaning. It no longer means agree or disagree, it means the sum of all agreements. If this is what you want from a theoretical perspective- by all means do it. If the resulting variable *needs* to be dichotomous, than you can (again, if it fits with theoretical constraints) decide to do it differently, say only if all answers are `agree` code as 1, otherwise, 0.

**regarding crosstabulation** - cross tabulation deals with multinomial data without a problem. The variable can be categorical. So, assuming you do a simple addition to create a variable with a range of {0,3} it can be considered an ordered categorical variable with 4 ranks, which can be crosstabulated.

Note that performing a simple addition assumes that each of the questions constructing it have similar "weight" or importance. So that a respondent who answered `[0,1,1]` is equal to respondents who answered `[1,1,0]` and `[1,0,1]`.

Comment: can we convert the final variable [0,3] to dichotomous by dividing it to range variables lowest to mean => disagree and mean to highest => agree?

Comment: I wouldn't. Say the mean is 2.04 - that is, most subjects seem to agree on slightly more than 2 out of 3 questions. But then those who answered 2 agree will be categorized as disagree. It should depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: How can we divide it to dichotomous variable? with median? with mode? or some other way? because I can't have any interpretation to those levels [0,3]. In my actual case, there are more than 3 sub questions which gives me in the range up to [0,28].

Comment: Can I use average to calculate the combined variable and divide it into dichotomous by recodnig [0,0.5) -> 0 and [0.5,1] -> 1? or use mid point to divide the sum to dichotomous with mid value between lower and higher limit (1.5 in [0,3] )?

Comment: If the 28 questions are all equal parts (more or less) of a parent variable (e.g., parent:animal lover, children: cats? Dogs? Dolphins? Goats? Etc..) than you can calculate the mean of all binary answers and divide above and below the mean. But in the example above, especially with so many child variables, it will lead to ambiguity in the middle. Does it make sense that a person who scored 13 agree out of 28 will be labeled DISAGREE and one with 15 as AGREE? Why do you need a dichotomous variable in the end? Can't it have more categories?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i find this solution very useful. Could you please tell me if at the end I want three variables like low, medium and high, how can i do it? With mean i can decide just below and above the mean i.e. low or high.

Comment: Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers to the OP's question. 
CV is a strict Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Since you're new here, you may
want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Comment: You may want to use what you have written as a comment. But you will have to wait to have enough reputation to do that. Gung is right that you can't circumvent the rules by using the "Your Answer" field.